# How to force g++ to create C symbol name

Tags: ld, g++-4.7

I have a function called init in a cpp file, but when I compile it, g++ creates in the object file a symbol named _Z4initv, so when I link after with ld with the option -e init, obviously ld doesn't recognize the symbol init. Is there a way to create symbols name in C style with g++ ?

Comment: Ever seen `extern "C"` somewhere before? Never wondered what it does?

Comment: I have write #if define(__cplusplus)                                                                    extern "C"                                                                                                              #endif  in the beginning of my file

Answer (score 0):

If you have a definition like e.g.

```
void init() { ... /* some code */ ... }
```

Then to inhibit [*name mangling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) you need to declare it as `extern "C"`:

```
extern "C" void init() { ... /* some code */ ... }
```

---

If you have a declaration in a header file that you want to include in a C source file you need to check if you're including the header file in a C or C++ source file, using the `__cplusplus` macro:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
void init(void);
```

Note that the function in the header file has to be declared with `void` in the argument list, if it doesn't take any arguments. That's because the declaration `void init()` means *something else* in C.